# What's the domain of $x$ in the RHS of the following logical equivalence, $\forall x \in D, P(x) \equiv \forall x, x \in D \rightarrow P(x)$?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Given the following logical equivalence,
$$\forall x \in D, P(x) \equiv \forall x, x \in D \rightarrow P(x)$$

The LHS of the equivalence states that "for all $x$ in the domain $D$, $P(x)$". The RHS in the other hand states that "for all $x$, if $x$ is an element of $D$, then $P(x)$". From the book *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications* by Kenneth H. Rosen, he says that

> The domain must always be specified when a universal quantifier is used; without it, the universal quantification of a statement is not defined.

The RHS of the logical equivalence doesn't seem have a domain. I've also seen in a few places where people only write "$\forall x$" without specifying the domain, which would be understood as "$\forall x \in \mathbb{U}$", where $\mathbb{U}$ is the universe of discourse. Should it assumed that the domain of the RHS of the logical equivalence is the set $\mathbb{U}$ such that $D \subseteq \mathbb{U}$? Also, I know that the ["ultimate" universal set doesn't exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#Reasons_for_nonexistence) which means that the domain of $x$ can't just be the set of everything (I used to think that the domain of $x$ in this case would be the "ultimate" universal set).

If there's no universe of discourse, then wouldn't $\forall x, x \in D \rightarrow P(x)$ be not defined? What's the domain for $x$ in the RHS then?

Comment: The "universe of discourse" is specified by the interpretation.

Comment: The equiv above holds because the two formulas have the same truth value, whatever the interpretation is.

Comment: Yes in $\forall x$ the domain is the universe of discourse. Note also that in most cases (known to me) the equivalence you wrote above is a definition, not a result. You define $\forall_{x\in D} ~P(x)$ to mean $\forall_x( x\in D\rightarrow P(x))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mauro states in the Comments, it's all about interpretations.

Take a logic statement like $\forall x \ P(x)$

What does this say?  We read this as 'All objects have property $P$".  OK, but what exactly is this property $P$?  And what do you mean by 'all'? Indeed, what are we really talking about?

This is where interpretations come in. An interpretation might say: This sentence is about natural numbers, and $P(x)$ means that "$x$ is even". So under that interpretation, the above statement would mean that "all natural numbers are even".

OK, but there are many other interpretations possible. I could say that the domain is my clothes, and that $P(x)$ means "$x$ is red". So now the statement means "All my clothes are red".  A totally different statement

Part of the power of logic is that the statement itself doesn't fix any interpretation... and *therefore* point out interesting relationships about *any* domain. For example, you can show that $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\exists x \ \neg P(x)$, *no matter* what the domain is or what $P(x)$ means.

Now, in your case we use a restricted quantifier of the form $\forall x \in D ...$.  Again, when we use such a quantifier, we do often have some specific domain in mind ... but logic itself does not. So, you'll have to say what this $D$ is in the interpretation. And, here we do make the stipulation that whatever $D$ is, it is *part* of a larger domain. That is, the very idea of the restricted quantifier is of course that out of some larger domain, there exists a subset $D$ to which we want to restrict our claim.

So, the interpretation will have to define two groups of objects:  the group of objects represented by $D$, and the group of objects that the unrestricted quantifier $\forall x$ would range over, where we specify that the first group of objects is a subset of the latter group. But no, neither $D$ nor the larger domain is specified by the statement itself.

However, showing the power of logic once again, *no matter* what we pick for $D$, the larger domain that $D$ is a subset of, and $P$,  it will always have to be the case that $\forall x \in D, P(x)$ is true if and only if  $\forall x, x \in D \to P(x)$ is true. And that makes them logically equivalent statements.

Comment: I believe this means that $\forall x$ is an unrestricted quantifier which ranges over the universe of discourse (the set of everything we're talking about)?

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Correct